# If statement with %in% error Condition warning: has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I have a data frame `schedule` in R with 6 columns. If the value of the 1st column is in a specific list, I want to change the value of other columns.

Here is the code I tried and I get the error message `Condition warning: has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

```
if (schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520))
{
    schedule[,4:6]="Removed to contingency"
}
```

I have looked on the site for similar questions but i didn't find any with the %in%
Thank you very much for your help

This was resolved. Thank you very much for your help everyone

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that gives the error?  Can you edit your post and put in the results of `dput(head(schedule))` so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: @conlie Please don't edit your post to remove the details of the question, the way Stack Overflow is supposed to work is that you upvote all the answers that helped and "accept" the answer that helped the most to mark the question as resolved. By removing the details of your question, you've made it less useful to people who might have the same problem later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with the way you want to do this is that columns 4 to 6 are currently date types, but you can't put a string value like "Removed to contingency" into a date column without changing it to a string type. With that in mind, I think what you want is:

```
# Convert columns to character
for (i in 4:6) {schedule[, i] = as.character(schedule[, i])}
# Use logical subsetting to apply the change to the right rows
schedule[schedule$Complex_number %in% c(540,1040,1050,520), 4:6] = "Removed to contingency"
```

Which gives:

```
> schedule
  Complex_number Removal_begins Removal_complete     Begin_installation
1            450     2015-05-02       2015-05-13             2015-05-03
2            440     2015-05-23       2015-06-03             2015-05-24
3            650     2015-06-13       2015-06-24             2015-06-14
4            940     2015-07-04       2015-07-15             2015-07-05
5            950     2015-07-25       2015-08-05             2015-07-26
6            540     2015-08-08       2015-08-19 Removed to contingency
        First_production     Atplanned_capacity
1             2015-06-22             2015-06-06
2             2015-06-29             2015-06-27
3             2015-07-13             2015-07-04
4             2015-08-03             2015-07-25
5             2015-08-24             2015-08-15
6 Removed to contingency Removed to contingency
```

As you've seen from other answers, you *can* have `NA` values in date type columns, so you can keep those columns as date types. Marking those rows as `NA` is probably the more "R-like" way to go. In addition, you could create an extra column to record why the column was removed, like:

```
schedule$RemovedToContingency = schedule$Complex_number %in% c(540,1040,1050,520)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the entire first column of your data.frame to %in% (schedule[,1]), your %in% operation will return a vector of booleans, one for each element in the first column. Meanwhile, *if* only accepts one value.

%in% is returning something like this:

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE etc.
```

But *if* can only handle one value.

Maybe you want to use *any()*, which returns a single boolean value that indicates if any value in a given input is TRUE. So, if any element of column 1 were in your list, you would get a single value of TRUE. Please note that this is untested though.

```
if(any(schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but after doing this, all my columns 4 to 6 are now filled with "Removed to Contigency"

Comment: schedule[,4:6] selects the entirety of columns 4 through 6, not just one row. If you do x = which(schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520)) it should return the indices of the rows that are in your list. You can then do schedule[x,4:6], where x is one of the indices of rows that was returned by which()

Answer (score 0):

When you run `schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520)` you get a vector of logicals for each value of `schedule[,1]`, but `if()` statements only take one logical value, and the warning tells you that the first will be used. If you want to replace in case any of the values is true, you can use:

```
if (any(schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520)))
{
    schedule[,4:6]="Removed to contingency"
}
```

**Update:**

To replace only the rows with the problematic values, you can use:

```
schedule[schedule[,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520),][4:6] = NA
```

I switched your text to NA to avoid problems with the column class.

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't work, now my entire columns 4 to 6 are filled with "removed to contingency", instead of only the row where the first column was 540,1040,1050,520

Comment: As a sidenote, in R you usually don't have to use if statements or loops to manipulate data like this. There are many subsetting possibilites when you use all the comparision operators and functions.

Answer (score -1):

`if` statements can only handle one logical at a time. In your example, the if condition is producing a vector of logical values, i.e., it is testing if every row of column 1 is in c(540,1040,1050,520).

I would suggest wrapping a for loop around this:

```
n <- nrows(schedule)
for (i in seq_along(1:n)) {
if (schedule[i,1] %in% c(540,1040,1050,520)) {
      schedule[i,4:6]="Removed to contingency"
    }
}
```

There are more elegant ways to approach this, but this way requires little adjustment to your code.

Comment: I tried this code and nothing changes to the data frame even when schedule[,1] are actually equal to one of the value in the list